# How can I animate a point moving around the circumference of a circle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

With this code, how would it be possible to animate a point to trace the circle?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
F = X**2 + Y**2 - 0.6
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

I need it to look something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEnET3MO0Sw). (Sorry I couldn't find a better animation describing what I wanted) The point I'm describing would be the center point of the circle that the moon is rotating around.

Answer (score 4):

You need to parametrize your circle, such that each timestep gives a different coordinate on that circle. This would probably best be done in polar coordinates, where the angle directly gives you the parameter to vary.

```
r = 1 # radius of circle
def circle(phi):
    return np.array([r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)])
```

You then need to set up a matplotlib figure and axes and define an updating function, which, if called sets the position of a point to the values received from the above `circle` function.
You may then animate the whole thing via `FuncAnimation`, which repeatedly calls that updating function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,3
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

r = 1 # radius of circle
def circle(phi):
    return np.array([r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)])

# create a figure with an axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the axes limits
ax.axis([-1.5,1.5,-1.5,1.5])
# set equal aspect such that the circle is not shown as ellipse
ax.set_aspect("equal")
# create a point in the axes
point, = ax.plot(0,1, marker="o")

# Updating function, to be repeatedly called by the animation
def update(phi):
    # obtain point coordinates 
    x,y = circle(phi)
    # set point's coordinates
    point.set_data([x],[y])
    return point,

# create animation with 10ms interval, which is repeated,
# provide the full circle (0,2pi) as parameters
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=10, blit=True, repeat=True,
                    frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic and really helps. If you could comment your code that would be super helpful, I've been playing around trying to figure out what everything does. Though if your busy or don't want to, don't worry about it

Comment: I annotated the code. I thought it would be pretty self-explanatory, so best ask specifically about what you do not understand.

Comment: Where do you define the center point of the circle/if it defaults to 0,0, how could I

Comment: The circle is centered at (0,0) of course you can shift it, if you want, e.g. `np.array([r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)]) + np.array((0.2,-0.1))`.